# Cambiar el formato de la fecha actual con JQuery

Tags: jquery, date

Actualmente estoy mostrando la fecha actual de esta forma:

```
    var date = new Date();

 var time = date.getFullYear() +"-"+date.getFullMonth() +"-"+date.getDate() +" "+ date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
```

Pero el `new Date();` utiliza un formato que no necesito:

```
2017-4-16 11:7:48
```

El formato que necesito es:

```
2017-05-16 10:39:19 //año/mes/dia hh:mm:ss
```

Como puedo editar el metodo `Date()` para traer la fecha y hora que
necesito?

Comment: Mi intención no es usar plugins gracias saludos

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es sobreescribir el método toString de Date para que te devuelva el formato que tu quieres siempre con un new Date().toString()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto

```
var d = new Date();
var strDate = d.getFullYear() + "-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "-" + d.getDate() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
```

Comment: Sabes de que forma puedo agregar el cero a los meses ya los segundos estimado ?

Comment: Solo cambiale por esto var strDate = d.getFullYear() + "-" + "0" +(d.getMonth()+1) + "-" + d.getDate() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + "0" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();

Answer (score 0):

Basandome en la respuesta de @Gustavo Piris prueba lo siguiente:

```
var strDate = d.getFullYear() + "-" + ((d.getMonth()+1)<10?'0'+(d.getMonth()+1):(d.getMonth()+1)) + "-" + (d.getDate()<10?'0'+d.getDate():d.getDate()) + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + (d.getMinutes()<10?'0'+d.getMinutes():d.getMinutes()) + ":" + (d.getSeconds()<10?'0'+d.getSeconds():d.getSeconds());
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor es crear una función para formatear los valores según una mascara "00" (z2) ya que este principio aplica tanto a ***mes*** como a ***hora, minutos y segundos***.

Ejemplo:

```js
function zero(n) {
 return (n>9 ? '' : '0') + n;
}
var date = new Date();

var time = date.getFullYear() +"-"+zero(date.getMonth()+1) +"-"+zero(date.getDate()) +" "+ zero(date.getHours()) + ":" + zero(date.getMinutes()) + ":" + zero(date.getSeconds());

console.log(time);
```

**Respuesta Original:**

Puedes crear un nuevo método para el **mes** y los **segundos**.

Ejemplo:

```js
Date.prototype.mes = function() {
  var m = this.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-based
  return (m>9 ? '' : '0') + m;
};
Date.prototype.segundos = function() {
  var s = this.getSeconds();
  return (s>9 ? '' : '0') + s;
};

var date = new Date();
var dateFormat = date.getFullYear() + "-" + date.mes() + "-" + date.getDate() + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.segundos();

console.log(dateFormat);
```

Fuente: [get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066586/get-string-in-yyyymmdd-format-from-js-date-object)